# How do you simply read a u32 from a file?

Tags: file, rust

Alright I am very new to Rust and I'm making a modding tool port for my friend. I need to read in a gazitillion u32s from a file and I haven't found a simple solution for that. The function I came up with looks like this:

```
pub fn read_u32(filename: &String, offset: usize) -> u32{
    let data: Vec<u8> = std::fs::read(filename).unwrap();
    let sliced_data = &data[offset..(offset+4)];
    let mut value: u32 = 0;
    for i in 0..4{
        value += (sliced_data[3-i] as u32) * u32::pow(256, i as u32);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Now, this seems to be very, very slow. Quite obviously. How could I improve this function, or more like, with what can I replace it?

(Note: The u32s all are big endian)

Solution:

```
pub fn read_u32(filename: &String, offset: usize) -> u32{
    let mut file = std::fs::File::open(filename).unwrap();
    let mut buffer = [0; 4];
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(offset as u64)).unwrap();
    file.read(&mut buffer[..]).unwrap() as u32;

    return u32::from_be_bytes(buffer);
}
```

Thanks to @user1937198!

Comment: If you open the File into a File object you can use seek and then read to read just the 4 bytes your interested in, rather than the entire file, which is almost certianly the slow part.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_be_bytes will probably help with the rest of your problem.

Comment: You should not answer in your question and instead post a self-answer below.